# How to conditionally cast to multiple types in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm looking at a function with this pattern:

```
if( obj is SpecificClass1 )
{
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod1();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass2 )
{
   ((SpecificClass2)obj).SomeMethod2();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass3 )
{
   ((SpecificClass3)obj).SomeMethod3();
}
```

and get a code analysis warning: CA1800 Do not cast unnecessarily.

What's a good code pattern I can use to replace this code with that will be performant and concise.

**Update**

I didn't say, but obj is declared with type object.

I originally asked two questions here. I've split one off (which nobody had yet answered anyway): [Why wouldn't the compiler optimize these two casts into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987524/why-wouldnt-the-compiler-optimize-these-two-casts-into-one)

Comment: If you've got a bunch of these then consider whether you can eliminate it with overloading. Or generics.

Comment: @slugster - using a Visitor pattern? Unfortunately, I don't have access to modify the library that SpecificClassX comes from.

Comment: Can you look to hide the ugliness in an adapter class that extends the one from the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing a method

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool TryCast<T>(this object from, out T to) where T : class
    {
        to = from as T;
        return to != null;
    }
}
```

and using it:

```
SpecificClass1 sc1;
SpecificClass2 sc2;
SpecificClass3 sc3;

if( obj.TryCast(out sc1) )
{
    sc1.SomeMethod1();
}
else if( obj.TryCast(out sc2) )
{
    sc2.SomeMethod2();
}
else if( obj.TryCast(out sc3) )
{
    sc3.SomeMethod3();
}
```

Comment: You do have to be careful not to use one variable in a scope where it didn't cast. Eg, don't use sc1 in the body where sc2.SomeMethod2() is.

Answer (score 3):

### Interface

The best way would be to introduce an interface that all the types implement. This is only possible  if the signatures match (or you don't have too many differences).

### Using as

If creating an interface is not an option, you can get rid of the CA message by using the following pattern (though this also introduces unnecessary casts and therefore degrades performance a bit):

```
var specClass1 = obj as SpecificClass1;
var specClass2 = obj as SpecificClass2;
var specClass3 = obj as SpecificClass3;
if(specClass1 != null)
   specClass1.SomeMethod1();
else if(specClass2 != null)
   specClass2.SomeMethod2();
else if(specClass3 != null)
   specClass3.SomeMethod3();
```

You can also change it to this structure (from my point of view, the above is better in terms of readability):

```
var specClass1 = obj as SpecificClass1;
if (specClass1 != null)
   specClass1.SomeMethod1();
else
{
    var specClass2 = obj as SpecificClass2;
    if (specClass2 != null)
        specClass2.SomeMethod2();
    else
    {
        var specClass3 = obj as SpecificClass3;
        if (specClass3 != null)
            specClass3.SomeMethod3();
    }
}
```

### Registering the types in a dictionary

Also, if you have many types that you want to check for, you can register them in a dictionary and check against the entries of the dictionary:

```
var methodRegistrations = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object> act>();
methodRegistrations.Add(typeof(SpecificClass1), x => ((SpecificClass1)x).SomeMethod1());
methodRegistrations.Add(typeof(SpecificClass2), x => ((SpecificClass2)x).SomeMethod2());
methodRegistrations.Add(typeof(SpecificClass3), x => ((SpecificClass3)x).SomeMethod3());

var registrationKey = (from x in methodRegistrations.Keys 
                       where x.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()).FirstOrDefault();
if (registrationKey != null)
{
    var act = methodRegistrations[registrationKey];
    act(obj);
}
```

Please note that the registrations are easily extendable and that you can also call methods with different arguments in the action.

Comment: Wouldn't that incur a performance penalty though. This code always does a cast for each SpecificClass type, even though the first one might match... so in that case only one cast would be needed, I think.

Comment: I rather to soft cast as needed But i don't like the nested if/else; i rather have an explicit return or simple if at the same level with no 'else'

Comment: @ScottLangham: yes, that's what I meant with 'unnecessary casts'. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the double casting you could do the following

```
var objClass1= obj as SpecificClass1;
if(objClass1!=null)
   objClass1.SomeMethod1();
```

Regarding the pattern you could make all these classes implement a common interface and make your method receive the interface.

```
public void SomeMethod(ISpecificInterface specific)
{
  specific.SomeMethod1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this here?

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class Implementer1:IBaseInterface
{

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Implementer2 : IBaseInterface
{

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Implementer3 : IBaseInterface
{

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then, in caller code:

```
IBaseInterface concrete = GetInstance();
            concrete.SomeMethod();
```

and `GetInstance` would create class objects based on conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes can be inherite a ISomeMethodInterface like this:

```
  public interface ISomeMethodInterface
{ 
     void SomeMethod();
}

public class SpecificClass1 : ISomeMethodInterface
{ 
 //some code
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class SpecificClass2 : ISomeMethodInterface
{ 
 //some code
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class SpecificClass3 : ISomeMethodInterface
{ 
 //some code
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

And in your call:

```
((ISomeMethodsInterface)obj).SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, bit rough, but:

```
    public class BaseClass{}

    public class SubClass1 : BaseClass  
    {
        public void SomeMethod1()
        {
        }
    }

    public class SubClass2 : BaseClass  
    {
        public void SomeMethod2()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            var test = new SubClass1();

            var lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
                             {
                                 {typeof (SubClass1), o => ((SubClass1) o).SomeMethod1() },
                                 {typeof (SubClass2), o => ((SubClass2) o).SomeMethod2() }
                             };

            //probably best to check the type exists in the dictionary first, 
            //maybe wrap up the execution into a class of it's own so it's abstracted away
            lookup[test.GetType()](test);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most extensible solution would probably be inheriting the concrete class while implementing an interface with a `SomeMethod` implementation that calls the correct `SomeMethodx` method on the inherited class. That way, you'll keep the existing interface while still keeping the existing methods.

```
public interface ISomething {
    void SomeMethod();
}

public SpecificClass1Wrapper : SpecificClass1, ISomething {
    void SomeMethod() { SomeMethod1(); }
}
```

If the objects are wrapped in this way before they're stored in the object reference, a cast to `ISomething` and a call to `SomeMethod()` will replace your entire if/else combination.

If the object on the other hand comes from code you have no way of extending and terse but still clear is what you're going for, you could create a simple helper method;

```
private bool CallIfType<T>(object obj, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    var concrete = obj as T;

    if (concrete == null)
        return false;

    action(concrete);
    return true;
}
```

You can then write the calls as a simple expression;

```
var tmp = CallIfType<SpecificClass1>(obj, x => x.SomeMethod1()) ||
          CallIfType<SpecificClass2>(obj, x => x.SomeMethod2()) ||
          CallIfType<SpecificClass3>(obj, x => x.SomeMethod3());

if(tmp)
    Console.WriteLine("One of the methods was called");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing a goal, but here's an option that should work.

```
if( obj is SpecificClass1 sc1 )
{
   sc1.SomeMethod1();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass2 sc2 )
{
   sc2.SomeMethod2();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass3 sc3 )
{
   sc3.SomeMethod3();
}
else
{
   throw new exception();
}
```

You can also

```
switch (obj)
{
    case SpecificClass1 sc1:
        sc1.SomeMethod1();
        break;
    case SpecificClass2 sc1:
        sc2.SomeMethod2();
        break;
    case SpecificClass3 sc1:
        sc3.SomeMethod3();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception();
}
```