# Why wouldn't the compiler optimize these two casts into one?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at a function with this pattern:

```
if( obj is SpecificClass1 )
{
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod1();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass2 )
{
   ((SpecificClass2)obj).SomeMethod2();
}
else if( obj is SpecificClass3 )
{
   ((SpecificClass3)obj).SomeMethod3();
}
```

and get a Code Performance Analysis Warning: CA1800 Do not cast unnecessarily.

Why do the double casts (using the 'is' operator in the if expression and the parenthesis style cast in the body of each if) not get optimized away by the compiler. I can't see why this would be a performance problem the compiler can't solve.

Comment: I originally asked this as part of the following question, but decided it's worth an S.O. question of its own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987025/how-to-conditionally-cast-to-multiple-types-in-c-sharp

Comment: It could do this, I suppose, but I guess the optimizer simply doesn't analyse this case. The example provided is very easy, but more complicated code could be hard to optimize. And there is the possibility of using `as` instead of `is` which makes the code easier to read and gets rid of the need for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: However, the code smells like the design could be improved somewhere. For example `obj` could be of an `abstract` compile-time type `NonSpecificBase`. That class could then have an `abstract` method `SomeMethod()` which each of the three specific classes could implement or override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote Eric Lippert (who used to work on the C# team):

> I am asked "why doesn't C# implement feature X?" all the time. The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature. All six of those things are necessary to make a feature happen. All of them cost huge amounts of time, effort and money. Features are not cheap, and we try very hard to make sure that we are only shipping those features which give the best possible benefits to our users given our constrained time, effort and money budgets.

Comment: -1: This answer does not demonstrate an understanding of the problem at hand. The feature may be implemented, but even if it were its impact would limited due to language semantics and the warning would remain appropriate since the optimization is not required by the language.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the compiler would prefer you to change:

```
if( obj is SpecificClass1 )
{
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod1();
}
```

to

```
SpecificClass1 Class1Obj = obj as SpecificClass1;
if (Class1Obj != null)
{
   Class1Obj.SomeMethod1();
}
```

Yes, it is conceivable that the compiler could do the transformation for you. However, I guess that the compiler team decided that it would be better for the compiler to warn, and ask you to make the change.

Imagine if your original code had read:

```
if( obj is SpecificClass1 )
{
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod1();
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod2();
   ((SpecificClass1)obj).SomeMethod3();
}
```

At that point I think you can agree that purely for clarity it is better for the code to be modified by the programmer. At which point, if the code is better written the other way which happens to be more efficient as well as clearer, what is the point of implementing the optimisation?

Comment: In the latter example, the compiler couldn't perform the optimization unless `obj` is a local variable, since its value may have been changed during the call to `SomeMethod1()`.

Comment: @280Z28 if the compiler did the cast before the `if` (as the programmer should) then your `SpecificClass1` reference _is local_ and can't be changed.

Comment: @Gusdor I was referring to the example with 3 explicit casts.

Comment: @280Z28 That's the case for the first example too. It's not just a call to `SomeMethod1` that could change a non-local `obj`. For instance, a different thread could do so. Even for a local variable, the compiler would need to verify that the `obj` reference had not been passed to some other party.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are you suggesting that it is _bad_ for the compiler to remove implicit race conditions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The read operations of `obj` in the first example appear sequentially. They could be collapsed into a single read operation without breaking the memory model.

Comment: @280Z28 I suppose so. Ultimately the compiler team will have decided that their solution was better. I do agree with them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am merely pointing out that in *some* cases the optimization cannot be performed by the compiler. You showed one such example, so I referenced it specifically so people can see that the scope of this issue expands beyond what may be obvious at first glance. Since I didn't need two examples, I didn't make mention of the other example to avoid confusing readers who may be less familiar with this type of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching: the answer is in the [warning description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx).

I was right, the compiler is looking for `as` expression in this case which would spare you the two casts (`is` and `()` cast):

```
Derived d = new Derived();
Base b = d as Base;
if (b != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```

You are actually doing two casts, since the `is` is also performing a cast-type operation.

Comment: I realize I'm doing two casts. I was wondering why a warning was given instead of the compiler essentially doing the conversion you've given.

Answer (score 1):

The second cast *may* be omitted by an optimizing compiler, but it is not required to do so, and the C# memory model may prevent the application of this optimization in many common cases. If you always use the preferred form with the `as` operator, you gain the benefits of this "optimization" regardless of whether the compiler implements special logic to detect and optimize these cases.